Is there any quantity/unit that represent Mass $\times$ Velocity $\times$ Distance?
I don't know, it seems like Mass $\times$ Velocity $\times$ Distance should represent something important in Physics. Like more mass = more energy, more velocity = more energy, more distance travel = more energy. Also all moving object related to Mass, Velocity, Distance.
Just like Force (F) = Mass x Acceleration, I think there should be something representing Mass x Velocity x Distance.
I searched Google for "Mass x Velocity x Distance" or "Mass times Velocity times Distance" or "mvs" but no luck so far. Seems like no one interested in this. But my instinct tells me that there should be something about the value of this equation.

"Angular momentum" might be a hot guess...

... and therefore "action."  This has nothing to do with instinct...

In what scenario would these units appear?

There is, in principle, no correlation between distance traveled and energy used, though there could be a correlation in some specific case. E.g., in car travel. But, the need to supply energy for car travel arises from interactions between tires and pavement and, between a bulky body and viscous air. It's not for any fundamental reason that only depends on mass and velocity.

Without a $v^2$, you shouldn't be talking about energy.
Of course distance$^1$ is velocity times time:
$$ x = v\Delta t $$
so your quantity is:
$$ mv^2 \Delta t $$
which has a kinetic energy term in it, so:
$$ E\Delta t $$
Now that looks pretty interesting, since it has the same units as $\hbar$, which is many things:

angular momentum
action
Joules per hertz for quantized waves
$\sigma_x\sigma_p$ for wave functions

etc.
[1] When did we start using $s$ for distance? I know it's a path length on a curve but as a rando length...negative.

$s$ is used for displacement in several high school textbooks I've seen, including the IBDP syllabus, which I generally consider to be high quality for school physics.

@MariusLadegårdMeyer I know. The decision to have "$suvat$-equations" was an educrat decision, and I don't like it. My son just went though it, and it was like "apply the formula and shut up" rather than: understand what constant acceleration does in all cases. i.e, a differential equation and boundary values, which is what you should learn.
